# Having two sets of values in $scope.result in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use the following code to display the result of a research :

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in result">
    <td><div ng-click="display(x)">{{x}}<div></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

I use the following `$http.post` query to set values to `$scope.result`:

```
 $http.post('server.php', {"data" : $scope.keywords, "serverQuery" : "chercherAssociation"})
 .success(function(data, status) 
 {
     $scope.result = data;
 }
```

However, I need to change the code to something like this :

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in result">
        <td><div ng-click="display(x.id)">{{x.name}}<div></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

So `$scope.result` will need to have two sets of values : **id** and **name**.
How do I do that ?

I have tried the following :

```
$scope.result.name = ...
$scope.result.id = ...
```

and some variations, but it didn't work (nothing show up in the `<table>`).

Comment: I think `$scope.result` is an array, so you can use `indexer` like `$scope.result[0].name`, note: `0` for first element

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the form of `data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need add an element to $scope.result same as:

```
$scope.result = [];
$scope.result.push({id: .., name: ...})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a loop after your AJAX call, and fill your new results array:

```
$scope.result = [];

$http.post('server.php', {"data" : $scope.keywords, "serverQuery" : "chercherAssociation"})
 .success(function(data, status) {
     data.forEach(function (item) {
         // item.id & item.name is an example, uses what you need to get the values
         $scope.result.push({id: item.id, name: item.name});
     });
 }
```

Anyway, it's better to define some class or factory so it'll be easier to manage for future changes:

```
module.factory("MyClass", [ function() {
    var MyClass = function (remoteData) {
        this.id = remoteData.id; // Or whatever you get your id
        this.name = remoteData.name; // Or whatever you get your name
    };

    return MyClass;
}]);
```

Then inject your class in your controiller or whatever and use it, instead of using raw objects like {id: ..., name: ....}

Enjoy

Answer (score -1):

You can define $scope.result as an array object,each object in this array have two attribute:id and name.like this:

```
var $scope.result = [];
var one = {"id":1,"name":"hello"};
var two = {"id":2,"name":"world"};
$scope.result[0] = one;
$scope.result[1] = two;
```

Have a try.